# The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISelectInput'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I tried to pass an event to my onChange event. But I get intrinsic error all the time.

I made my selectInputInterface format this way:

```
interface ISelectInput {
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange: () => void;
  children: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

Then, my onChange function:

```
const handleSelectCategory = (event: any) => {
    const category = event.target.value;

    setSelectedCategory(category);
  };
```

I implemented in my UI:

```
<SelectInput
   placeholder="Select input"
   onChange={handleSelectCategory}
 >
    {uniqueCategories}
</SelectInput>

But I got this typescript error:
```

Type '(event: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
SelectInput.tsx(29, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISelectInput'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are contravariant with respect to their parameters. This also includes arity. In other words, you can assign a `() => void` to `(event: any) => void`, but not the other way around. That's because if I assign a `(event: any) => void` to somewhere that expects `() => void`, the function will be called *without an argument*, and therefore it is unsound.

It is a simple fix, however. Just define `onChange` to take an argument:

```
interface ISelectInput {
    placeholder?: string;
    onChange: (event: any) => void;
    children: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

I would also suggest that instead of using `any`, you should use the proper type, perhaps an `InputEvent`.

[Playground (demonstrating use of InputEvent with guard clauses)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkBlJAGyQxerACu8AN7k44uGE5MAFhE4ATegH4AXHADOMKDQDmFCXAjUAwjJTVdSdQAokANyS11fQTACij2gEo4AXgA+OHsIYAUKAF9KNGMtOABtDS4eOgUTFDpdaABPABpNJBgObgwkNIykLKhsgF1-RGIYADoBJLYYCpt8fG8KchjqOPNqBW5ilPTMnPq7LxgXfiFPJxhfQLhRQwG4jqgreD84BxWm3f2+w2BMOBsAQjPCuAAfJ7hbmwf4Gi0LNCQIa4ACQAKgBZAAyriW3BAK2er0+cG+HWofwBcBBEPGGHcMJW3l8RBgAig1AuEm28DQFSq2Xqnya9hQnAESHJ4iSRWSpXKU2qNmpfOyvXIET6mAEqJgwGMcGxMChMBsYBwYA0Lnlit8mwkRJJ1DgAB4FMB7AFDQB6E1myKUQ2axbwKSyeRKKB+fDypGO-BGUzDKx+YTDUZIeWTSo5CJwC0BChAA)

Answer (score 0):

Its because the function signature is different and does not take any params.

You can add a ...args do this

```
interface ISelectInput {
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange: (...args: any) => void;
  children: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

or use your event as optional and do

```
interface ISelectInput {
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange: (event?: any) => void;
  children: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because onChange in IselectInput is of type () => void, that is, it should receive a function with no input. But here, the handleSelectCategory function receives an (event).
For this error, you need to change the handleSelectCategory function from event: ‍`string` because at the end of the code, I want to pass a value from event.target.value (selected value from SelectInput) to setSelectedCategory as the selected category.

```js
interface ISelectInput {
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange: (category: string) => void;
  children: Record<string, any>[];
}

const handleSelectCategory = (event: any) => {
  const category = event.target.value;
  setSelectedCategory(category);
};

<SelectInput
  placeholder="Select input"
  onChange={handleSelectCategory}
>
  {uniqueCategories}
</SelectInput>
```